# Getting 3 divs spaced equal-vertically inside another div

Tags: html, css

So I have a problem I need to tackle when I get in to work today. I have 3 divs inside another div and I want the 3 inner divs to be equally spaced with the first at the very top and the third at the very bottom. These divs are of a fixed height and I want them to stay equally spaced even if I change the height of the outer div.

I've recreated the problem the scenario so that you can show me what I need to add. I know there's probably something involving `auto` that I need to do. If you give a good explanation, then I might choose you as best answer.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vp3uzvrz/

CSS:

```
div.outer
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

div.inner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be pushed against the top of the blue div</p>      
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be smack-dab between the other two </p>      
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be pushed against the bottom of the blue div</p>      
   </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: you can treat p tags as your div and valign the text for equal spacing

Comment: what do you mean by at the very top...do you at the top of outer container or on the top of other divs...if former is what you want....then i think it cannot be achieved through css only....i.e if you keep the spacing between the inner divs fixed...then the inner divs height have to be generated dynamically ( outercontainer height - total innermargins )/3....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` in your container and `display: table-row` in `inner` class. Also i add a `div` as a seperator between each row.

```css
div.outer
{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: table;
    height: 400px;
}

div.inner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be pushed against the top of the blue div</p>       
   </div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be smack-dab between the other two </p>      
   </div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be pushed against the bottom of the blue div</p>      
   </div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>    
</div>
```

As you can see you can add or remove a seperator:

```css
div.outer
{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: table;
    height: 400px;
}

div.inner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be pushed against the top of the blue div</p>       
   </div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be smack-dab between the other two </p>      
   </div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be pushed against the bottom of the blue div</p>      
   </div>  
   <!--<div class="seperator"></div>-->
</div>
```

And last:

```css
div.outer {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: table;
    height: 400px;
}
div.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="seperator"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>This should be pushed against the top of the blue div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>This should be smack-dab between the other two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>This should be pushed against the bottom of the blue div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seperator"></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you added a div called `separator` when you never defined it in the CSS?

Comment: Doesn't need to use it in css. Just need to add an element there as seperator between each row.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/vp3uzvrz/4/

basivally I used position absolute with this value:

```
.inner1, .inner2, .inner3
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
}
.inner1 {top:0}
.inner2 {
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px; /*half div height negative margin*/
}
.inner3 {bottom:0}
```

Don't forget to add position:relative to the container

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your 3 divs serperately, and using and y positioning to place them where you want, or bring the vertical length of your blue div upwards, tightening it to the edge of your bottom div.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) will also get you there.

```
div.outer
{
    display: flex;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4m809ax/1/

This is just the overall version; the fiddle has a whole mess of browser-specific variations. And make sure to check what your browser requirements are: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Answer (score 0):

```
div.outer
{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:relative;
    resize:vertical;
}

div.inner
{
    height: 30%;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
}

div.inner:first-child{
    top:0;
}

/*middle child*/
div.inner:nth-child(2){
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
div.inner:last-child{
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vp3uzvrz/8/

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
div.outer
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display:table;
}

div.inner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display:table-row;
}

p {
    display:table-cell;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be pushed against the top of the blue div</p>      
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be smack-dab between the other two </p>      
   </div>
   <div class="inner">
       <p>This should be pushed against the bottom of the blue div</p>      
   </div>    
</div>
```

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/ibbatta/vp3uzvrz/9/